# Adding custom extjs module in TYPO3 backend

Tags: typo3

I'm currently trying to create a node resolver for a TCA column. I've added a resolver and an element. The render function in the element class looks like this

```
public function render()
{
    $resultArray = $this->initializeResultArray();
    $resultArray['requireJsModules'][] = 'MyVendor/MyExtension/MyModule';
    $resultArray['html'] = 'Hallo Welt';
    return $resultArray;
}
```

The extjs modules is placed in *typo3conf/ext/my_extension/Resources/Public/JavaScript/MyModule.js*

When TYPO3 renders my element, it renders the html part and tries to load the extjs module with the path *typo3/MyVendor/MyExtension/MyModule.js*

My question now is, how can I add my custom extjs module, that is injected by require function in JavaScript?

I'm using TYPO3 7.6.15.

I'm thankful for every help :)

Comment: Please keep in mind that ExtJS is deprecated and will be removed in future TYPO3 versions (properly in v9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer here https://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/210780/ 
The module needs to have TYPO3/CMS as vendor. Than it load loaded correctly.

```
public function render()
{
    $resultArray = $this->initializeResultArray();
    $resultArray['requireJsModules'][] = 'TYPO3/CMS/MyExtension/MyModule';
    $resultArray['html'] = 'Hallo Welt';
    return $resultArray;
}
```

The module needs to be in typo3conf/ext/my_extension/Resources/Public/JavaScript/MyModule.js